# Who can see the revisions of the "About Me" field used in the user profiles?

Tags: support, profile-page, user-accounts

Who can see the previous text used in the "About Me" field of the user profiles?
Supposing I notice a user wrote something rude or offensive in that field, what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that field has revisions, it's just `Users.AboutMe` in the database. If you see a profile that's currently offensive, flag one of the user's posts for mod attention and mention it, and a mod will look into it. If it was offensive and they already fixed it, there's not really anything to look into anymore

Comment: Is it better to flag a post, or to ask on the chat?

Comment: @kiamlaluno - flag a post.

Comment: @kiamlaluno If the mods on the site you're looking at have a room dedicated to that (e.g. [Ask a Super User moderator](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator)) then that's fine, but I'd think they'd prefer you to use flags so it's tracked within the existing infrastructure for this sort of thing